# Anti-patching checksum

Tags: debugging, x64dbg, anti-debugging, hash-functions

I'm busy with debugging a program in x64dbg and it has some kind of anti-patching mechanism so can someone please advise me on how I would go about finding the functions which are calculating the programs hash value or where it is stored. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted? IMO such scenarios are not uncommon in practice.

Comment: Not mine, but maybe because of lack of details on any effort expended so far .

Comment: As it stands the question is really too broad aside from being opinion-based. I agree that the issue comes up in practice, but answers have a size limit (trust me, I _know_!) and no one wants to read a book when coming to a Q&A site such as this one. Please vote to reopen after you provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

For finding the software part calculating the hash value, just some possibilities:

- Look for "magic numbers" in the code. Many CRC, SHA etc standard
  checksum calculators could be recognized.

Often the hashes are
calculated across the whole image of e.g. a critical DLL.
In that case, you could look for

- LoadLibrary calls (in Windows)
- Magic numbers of the DLL itself, like (again Windows) the MS header "MZ", present in all DLLs and exe's produced with MS tools.

If you could find an algorithm, have a look where it stores values. This gives a hint about the location of the checksum.

And if you found the address where the hash is residing, set a "read" breakpoint (hardware breakpoint) on it and wait until it triggers. This could be the hash-checking routine.

"Windows" here of course as an example only. Similar strategies exist for other platforms.